# Linear process of birth using generating function

Tags: markov-chains, generating-functions, poisson-process, birth-death-process

How do I solve Kolmogorov differential equations for linear process of birth using generating function?

By linear process of birth I mean Poisson process for which

$$q_{i,i+1}=i\lambda\\
q_{i,i}=-i\lambda\\
q_{i,j}=0
$$

System of KDE is given as
$$p_k'(t)=-k\lambda p_k(t)+(k-1)\lambda p_{k-1}(t)$$
with initial value $p_1(0)=1$.

Using the generating function
$$G(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^Np_kx^k$$

we get the time derivative

$$\frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t}=-\sum_{k=0}^Nk\lambda p_kx^k+\sum_{k=1}^N(k-1)\lambda p_{k-1}x^k=\\=-x\lambda\sum_{k=0}^Nk p_kx^{k-1}+x^2\lambda \sum_{k=1}^N(k-1)p_{k-1}x^{k-2}
=\lambda(x^2-x)\frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial x}$$

hence
$$-\frac{dx}{\lambda(x^2-x)}=dt$$
$$x=\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{e^{\lambda t}-C}$$
$$C=e^{\lambda t}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Now using the initial value

$$G(x,t)=f\left[e^{\lambda t}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]$$
$$G(x,0)=f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=x\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{1-y}$$

Which gives us

$$G(x,t)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\lambda t}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-e^{\lambda t}+\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{x}}$$

However this doesn't seem to come close to giving the correct solution for absolute probability which is

$$p_k(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\left(1-e^{-\lambda t}\right)^{k-1}$$.

Have I made a mistake in my calculations or is there actually a way to get to this solution with my result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you found is consistent with the solution,
$$\frac{1}{\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{x}-e^{\lambda t}+1  }=\frac{xe^{-\lambda t}}{1-x(1-e^{-\lambda t})}=xe^{-\lambda t}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \bigl(x(1-e^{-\lambda t})\bigr)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k(t)x^k \,.$$